# What is a "mechanism" in PKCS11?

Tags: security, rsa, digital-signature, pkcs#11

What does *mechanism* mean in PKCS11? For example: `CKM_RSA_PKCS`.

What is the difference between a mechanism (`CKM_RSA_PKCS`) and a signature algorithm (`NoneWithRSA`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mechanism is a constant value that describes a cryptographic operation. For example, `CKM_RSA_PKCS` is defined in the PKCS #11 manual as:

> The PKCS #1 v1.5 RSA mechanism, denoted **CKM_RSA_PKCS**, is a multi-purpose 
>   mechanism based on the RSA public-key cryptosystem and the block formats initially 
>   defined in PKCS #1 v1.5. It supports single-part encryption and decryption; single-part 
>   signatures and verification with and without message recovery; key wrapping; and key 
>   unwrapping. This mechanism corresponds only to the part of PKCS #1 v1.5 that 
>   involves RSA; it does not compute a message digest or a DigestInfo encoding as 
>   specified for the  `md2withRSAEncryption` and `md5withRSAEncryption`
>   algorithms in PKCS #1 v1.5.

Note the "multi-purpose" clause - this single mechanism can be used with encryption/decryption as well as signing/verifying.

The Java mechanism `NoneWithRSA` is [defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature):

> The RSA signature algorithm which does not use a digesting algorithm (e.g. MD5/SHA1) before performing the RSA operation. For more information about the RSA Signature algorithms, please see PKCS1.

The Java mechanism is only for signatures.

From the descriptions, it appears a signature computed with `NoneWithRSA` in Java would be equivalent to a signature computed in PKCS #11 with `CKM_RSA_PKCS`.